# How to use explicit links with Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, hyperlink, thymeleaf

I wanted to make and link to external site in Spring+Thymeleaf web application and inserted link like this: `<a th:href="@{https://example.com}">Link</a>`

However by clicking the link it tries to point internal location `http://localhost/service/https://example.com` not external website https://example.com like it supposed to.

Site gives just an error `"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized."`

What's wrong and how to make absolute links with Thymeleaf?

Comment: Why don't you just use `<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>` or `<a th:href="https://example.com">Link</a>`?

Comment: Not an answer - just an observation: That syntax is correct. Something else (a filter? Spring?) may be rewriting the URL. Just as a test, what happens if you hard-code the URL: `<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>`? Or even `<a th:href="@{'https://example.com'}">Link</a>`?

Comment: `<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>` doesn't work either, it acts exactly the same. I'm trying to find how something could rewrite the URL or how it can be disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the application was built on top of other Spring+Thymeleaf project. Only way I got link working was like this.

`<a th:text="link" th:onclick="|window.location.href='@{https://example.com}'|"></a>`

I know this is not a "real" link and cannot be configure to open with `target="_blank"` or so but it's working with this use case.

Answer (score 0):

If the link is a static one You can simply use
`<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>`

If it is a dynamic one,
You can use `<a th:href="${link}">Link</a>` in the template. And in Controller
`return new ModelAndView("page").addObject("link", <link>)`

Comment: Basic HTML link `<a href="https://example.com">Link</a>` doesn't work either, it works exactly the same here. Link points to `http://LOCALWEBSITE/service/https://example.com` not `https://example.com` like I excpect.

Comment: `<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ecomselfmade" target="_blank" class="text-gray-350"><img src="/icons/instagram.svg" width="24" height="24" alt=""></a>`

I use this in my template and it works as expected
@JukkaS.